# Sending out two textboxes as opposed to one dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, buttonclick

I got this code from a previous post on here about dynamically making a panel based ona click event of a button.  For some reason its giving me two textbox's and I'm having issues deciphering the code.  Been a while since I've dealt with this kind of C#.  It's probably a simple fix, however like i said, been a while. 
The ASP.net code is just a button so no need to paste it.

C#:

```
public partial class Testing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add any controls that have been previously added dynamically
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; ++i)
    {
        AddControls(i + 1);
    }

    // Attach the event handler to the button
    Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);


}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Increase the number added and add the new label and textbox
    TotalNumberAdded++;
    AddControls(TotalNumberAdded);

}
private void AddControls(int controlNumber)
    {
        var newPanel = new Panel();
        var newLabel = new Label();
        var newTextbox = new TextBox();

        // textbox needs a unique id to maintain state information
        newTextbox.ID = "TextBox_" + controlNumber;

        newLabel.Text = "Nature Of Accident";

        // add the label and textbox to the panel, then add the panel to the form
        newPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(newTextbox);
        form1.Controls.Add(newPanel);
    }

    protected int TotalNumberAdded
    {
        get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the Button1.Click line from your pageload.

```
 Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

if your your .aspx button already looks something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

then that means that when you click the button, your code is going to go through the Page_Load, which means it will execute your Eventhandler for Button1_Click, and after that it will go further down to your actual events, being Button1_Click *again*, so thats basically why you get 2 textboxes.

Comment: no problem! you seem new to SO, so im just saying that, if you found an answer helpful, you may choose to upvote or accept it :)

Comment: i wish i could, dont have a 15+ rep yet :(

Comment: Also, this is for an asp.net form, I forget how to write HTML into the script in this circumstance >_< I feel like such a noob, I want to format the text box's i am going to customize it into a full form with 4 textboxes and 4 labels and i want to do it in table form

Comment: what exactly do you want to do ? i dont understand

Comment: Format it so that the labels and texbox's are in a table so that it looks clean, i know how to write the code i just dont know where to put it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160847/adding-controls-to-a-table-control-dynamically check this link out, it shows how to put your labels and textboxes in a table dynamically.

Comment: Kinda understanding it, any chance you can give me an example? In this circumstance within a panel?

Comment: i dont really have the time atm, maybe its better to post a new question, as what you are asking now doesn't really fit your original question anymore. But there are plenty of examples online on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Does your button have an event tied to it already in the asp page?

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

That seems like it could give you some problems, especially on reloads.